# How to implement multiple fragments in single Activity

Tags: android

I am trying to implement 2 fragments in a single activity, one beside other. The problem here is when I click an item in Fragment1, fragment should be updated in the same place where it is placed previous. But when I click an item in Fragment1, fragment is displayed over Fragment1.

How can I sort out this issue?

Comment: Please be more specific. What fragments do you mean?

Comment: Not an answer is not an answer >_<

Comment: fragments were new API introdiced in Android 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the details you are trying to insert into your "second" fragment are being put into the same layout container as the "first" fragment? Hard to say based on the info you gave.